# Difference between 「〜 時{じ}に」 and 「〜 しながら」

Tags: usage, nuances

What is the difference between 「〜時{じ}に」 and 「 〜しながら」?
I know I can say 「緊張しながら」 - means "while worrying..". Would it be correct if I write it as 「緊張時に」?

Comment: I thought of 「時に」 as a separate part.. I even pronounced it like "kinchō toki ni" in my mind.. So thanks a lot for correcting me :)

Comment: 「きんちょうじに」で合ってます。音読み同士ですし。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「～しながら」 explicitly means two different things are happening concurrently.

「～時【じ】に」 literally means "at the time (of ～)". You may translate this as *when*, *if*, *before*, or *after*, depending on the context.

- 飲酒【いんしゅ】時【じ】に車を運転する drive a car *after* drinking (i.e. under the influence of alcohol)
- 飲酒しながら車を運転する drive a car *while* drinking (i.e., a steering wheel in one hand, and a can of beer in the other hand...)
- この薬は就寝【しゅうしん】時に飲んでください。 Take this medicine *before* going to bed.
- (*)この薬は就寝【しゅうしん】しながら飲んで下さい。 Take this medicine *while* asleep(?).
- 緊張しながら while being nervous, while feeling tension
- 緊張[時]{じ}に when/if I feel nervous